# How can I make my function calls sequential?

Tags: javascript

My code calls a function a specific amount of times and that amount is based on the current item of an array that is being looped through and this item is a number. So if the first item of the array is 9, the function is called 9 times and after that, whatever number the next item is, will be how many times the function is called again.

There is also a pause in between each set of  calls based on a number in the array. So once the function has been called the amount of times the first array item specifies with a number, there is a pause and the function is called again for the amount of times the second item in the array specifies with a number.

To better understand, the code below  calls the function called "thefunction" 8 times, then pauses, then calls the it 2 times then pauses, then 15 times. This is the array:    var theArray = ['8','2','15'];  So the code below goes through each item of the array and uses each array item, which is a number, to determine how many times it will call "thefunction" function. Here is my issue, when the function "thefunction" is called multiple times, I'm not having code execute properly.

I'm thinking this is because the calls to "thefunction" are not sequential. How can I modify the code below to make it so that when "thefunction" is called for a certain amount of times, the calls will be sequential in other words, the function will finish before it is called again. This way, if the first item in the array is the number 8 for example, "thefunction" will be called 8 times but actually be able to execute the code entirely each time before moving on to the next number item in the array.

```
 function runArray(arr, fn) {
 // initialize array index - can't use for loop here with async
 var index = 0;

 function next() {
 var cnt = +arr[index];
 for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
 fn(index, cnt);
 }
 // increment array index and see if there's more to do
 ++index;
 if (index < arr.length) {
       setTimeout(next, 400);
 }
}
// start the whole process if the array isn't empty
if (arr.length) {
   next();
}
}

var theArray = ['8','2','15'];
runArray(theArray, thefunction); //I'm calling the function called "thefunction" here
function thefunction(){
//my code. it doesn't get executed because calls aren't sequential I think
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of paragraphs? Makes things easier to read

Comment: The 8 calls, the 2 calls and the 15 calls are sequential, your problem is probably caused by something else.

Comment: The calls are indeed sequential, but if `thefunction` contains async calls, then of course they won't be executed sequentially. So it all depends on the contents of `thefunction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a queue be a suitable solution to this problem? You would split your code into two parts: one part adds functions to a queue, and another part regularly checks the queue. If there's something on it, it invokes that function. This example isn't an exact mapping to your situation, but it should demonstrate the approach:

```
var queue = [];

// Enqueue a function.
function addFunctionToQueue() { 
    var func = function() { console.log("I'm a queued function"); };
    queue.push(func);
}

// Check the queue for a function, and run it if found. 
function runQueue() { 
    var fn;
    while (fn = queue.shift()) { // [].shift() is undefined, and undefined is falsey
        fn();
    }
    console.log("No more work to do, runQueue() ending.");
}

// Enqueue a function every second, and check the queue every 500ms
setInterval(addFunctionToQueue, 1000);
setInterval(runQueue, 500);
```

If you generate a function that runs a passed-in function `n` times and add that function to your queue, then you can be sure that the functions will run in the order you enqueued them.